# Disable UIView respond to UIIntefaceOrientationDidChange

Tags: iphone, uiview, rotation, orientation, device

I have a uiimageview within a uiview and I would like it to not rotate when uiinterfaceorientationdidchange is called but I would like everything else to rotate. Right now everything is rotating, how can I set certain objects not to rotate?

Answer (score 0):

A `UIImage` has a property `imageOrientation`.  Or, make a custom view controller with only a `UIImageView` and in the `shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of thatcontroller return `NO`.  Then, in the interface builder for your main view controller, add a custom object and change its class to your custom UIImageView.  Or you can add it as a subview programatically.

Check out the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.